# angularjs Failed to instantiate module on LAMP but runs on WAMP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ubuntu

I have an application that Im migrating from my windows server to an Ubuntu 16.04 server. The code works fine on the windows server but Im getting the following errors when I move the code to the ubuntu server

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module engagerApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'engagerApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=engagerApp
>       at server_ip/public/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12

Im assuming that the code is fine as its working on another server but there is something missing from the ubuntu one. Its a fresh install with apache 2.4.18

Also everyone of my javascript files is erroring with the same message on line 1

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: The second error is a common error, it generally means your configuration for your server is not correct, and is either sending your index.html or sending a 404 page which is an HTML document for all your javascript requests.  the first character in any HTML document is `<`, and that isn't valid as the first character of a javascript file. Use chrome debugger to determine what files are being returned to figure out what is wrong with your server configuration.

Comment: how exactly should I determine the files that are being returned. In all of the files that are being marked as having that problem I have confirmed that they exist on the server and in the correct folder.

Comment: in chrome, debug tools (F12), go to the sources tab, and look at each file that is erroring, you should be able to piece together what the server is sending.

Comment: ah yes ok. All of the javascript files are returning the index.html

Comment: Sounds like you need to post your server configuration

Comment: the apache config?